# How do I change my username and include an acute accent?

Tags: support

I would like to change my username, which is currently a number.

The appropriate user name has an accent over the letter "e", specifically an acute accent.  What is the correct procedure to accomplish this?

Comment: To change your user name I think you only need to go to your profile in the main page, and in there you'll find an option to edit your profile (it is located to the right of where it says "Registered User"), and there you can change your "Display Name" which I think is what you want. And about the acute accent, my name has an acute accent and I didn't find any trouble with the system, it displays it correctly.

Comment: @ Adrián Barquero: But precisely how does one type in the proposed user name? In your case, it probably was not Adri\'{a}n.  LaTeX is all I know!

Comment: You could copy and paste the following: é. Using Windows, I typically have my keyboard set to "US International," which allows easy typing of accented characters.  E.g., typing `'e` produces é.  If you like the copy/paste method, you might want to bookmark the following: http://www.copypastecharacter.com/

Comment: Oh no, I only use my keyboard as usual. I press the button used for accents before I enter the corresponding vowel, and that's it, no Latex involved whatsoever. Isn't that the way in which you put accents when writing not in Latex? Oh and by the way, I suppose you know that there are packages in Latex that let you write accents in the usual way instead of having to write something like "\'{a}".

Comment: @Adrían: "as usual" depends on your locale :)

Comment: In my case I use a keyboard with accent keys. Américo.

Comment: ... In Portugal.

Comment: See also [How does one typeset accent marks outside of math mode?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1358/how-does-one-typeset-accent-marks-outside-of-math-mode)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

StackExchange software supports unicode. So if you can enter the accented characters directly via your input method of choice, it will work. If you don't know how to enter an accented character, one option is to use [Andrew Stacey's LaTeX-to-unicode converter](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/code/latexToUTF/utf.php) and then copy-and-paste the resulting character into the textbox.

Comment: Tried it, the process of producing the é clearly works just fine.  The system however refused to make the change.  But it assured me it wasn't my fault. That's good, otherwise the guilt would tear me up.

Comment: Fourth time lucky. Or did you do some magic?

Comment: Nothing was done by me per se. Nothing in the moderator log indicates your previous tries. It could be that your first three tries were when the StackExchange platform is undergoing maintenance or something like that.